# how can I get the original file type after user modification using PE header in legacy driver

Tags: c++, c, driver, portable-executable

I have developed a legacy driver to allow and block the transfer of specific files from hard disk to external devices. This works fine.

The issue I face is that, here the user is able to modify the file name and file file type.

How can I find the original file type and file name modified by user ?

Is it possible to find the original file type using portable executable header ?

(Files type for example .pdf,.txt)

During my research I found that they are able to find original file type.How do they find the original file type. Similar has been done by " http://checkfiletype.com/"

Thanks in advance. Can you provide any solution for this.

Comment: What kind of files do you want to block?  Is it possible to detect them by file content rather than by file name and extension?

Comment: That is all file-type dependent. Some files have a fixed header string, other have a footer. But regardless, if you're worried about renaming, what's next? Checking all compressed archives? What if a user encrypts the file and then copies it over?

Comment: If the code is not running on your hardware it's not your code anymore.

Comment: Services such as checkfiletype.com's and commands such as Unix's `file` identify file types by examining the file content and applying a series of rules.  Basically, they look for characteristic byte patterns.  They are more reliable for some file types then for others, but not 100% reliable for any file type.  They *may* consider file name as a fallback, but that is not a reliable indicator, and these programs know it.

Comment: I want to block and allow specific type of files for example .pdf,.txt,

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, *no* common file type stores its own file name.  That's a function of how and where the filesystem stores it, not of the file itself.

Comment: That's easier to do via group policy, you just don't allow programs that handle those file types

Comment: HI can you share some information regarding group policy

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/srvnodes/group-policy

Comment: What is your original requirement? Adding to PeterT's comment: There are ways to hide data, e.g. `.png` that contains a `.zip` file in combination with encrypted `.zip`.

Comment: Hi  John Bollinger. thanks for the replay. Can you provide some information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This game had a name.

The name of the game is "last one who moves wins"

I will gladly exfiltrate files by base85 encoding them and dropping that as content in an allowed type.

Your users will no doubt come up with other clever ways.

Now if you were doing this for virus control I'd say just examine file contents and if it looks like an executable say no. The first two characters of an executable file are always MZ.